# Flutter play animation once programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

I would like to trigger a `animate` programmatically but can not make it work. This is what I tried for my basic `scale`-animation:

```
Text(
    _getItemTitle(option),
    style: _wishState == option
        ? AppTextStyles.avenirNextH5SemiBold
        : AppTextStyles.avenirNextH5Regular,
  )
      .animate(
        onPlay: (controller) => _animationController.repeat(reverse: true),
      )
      .scale(
        end: const Offset(1.2, 1.2),
      ),
```

The animation should play once, including a reverse-animation. I tried adding a `controller` but how don't know how I can make that work. I would like to trigger it with a `Provider` I already setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this instead:

```
onPlay: (controller) => _animationController.loop(count:2, reverse: true),
```

Response to question in comment:

Use the target property in the `animate()` method to react to state changes, such as from your provider. See the docs:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animate#reacting-to-state-changes

Comment: but how would I trigger the `animation` from outside?

Comment: working like a charm. Forgot about `target`. Thanks :)